# If MATLAB is in the Ubuntu apps, does it means that its Open Source?

Tags: matlab

MATLAB is not a free software. In ubuntu apps page MATLAB is open source.
Does that mean it is free?

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to this: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/matlab-support/ ?

This app in the Ubuntu Software Centre isn't Matlab, but a package that adds the Matlab icon to the unity dash.

Matlab itself is closed source and non-free.